# How to get the contents between <li> tag using php?

Tags: php, html, parsing

I am trying to get the content between the `<li>` tag from an html code i have using php.

the code I have is

```
 <div class="container">
      <ul class="inside content">
         <li>number 1 </li>
         <li>number 2 </li>
         <li>number 3 </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="outside content">
         <li class="different class">number 1 </li>
         <li class="different class">number 2 </li>
         <li class="different class">number 3 </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

now i am trying to get the content with the `<li>` tag of both the `<ul>` tags separately. So can someone help me out with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the content"?

Comment: i want the content that is between <li> tags. that is number 1, number 2

Comment: Can't you just see it in the code?  Where do you want it?

Comment: if i am trying to select the ul with class = outside content as **ul.outside content** will it work. If no, what is the correct way.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand what you mean... you have that block of text as a string in your PHP.  Ramraider's post below is the way you'd want to go then.

Comment: Susan, the CSS selector you've quoted is not correct. To select that `ul` block, the selector is `ul.outside.content`. The dot is required to indicate `content` is a class, and there is no intervening space, to show it is an additional class of the same expression, not a child of the previous expression.

Answer (score 4):

using DOMDocument - untested but the idea is sound

```
        $strHTML=' <div class="container">
          <ul class="inside content">
             <li>number 1 </li>
             <li>number 2 </li>
             <li>number 3 </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="outside content">
             <li class="different class">number 1 </li>
             <li class="different class">number 2 </li>
             <li class="different class">number 3 </li>
          </ul>
     </div>';

    $aul1=array();
    $aul2=array();

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $strHTML );/* where $strHTML is the html you wish to parse*/
    $col=$dom->getELementsByTagName('li');

    foreach( $col as $node ) {
        if( $node && $node->parentNode->hasAttribute('class') && $node->parentNode->getAttribute('class')=='inside content' ) $aul1[]=$node->nodeValue;
        if( $node && $node->parentNode->hasAttribute('class') && $node->parentNode->getAttribute('class')=='outside content' ) $aul2[]=$node->nodeValue;
    }

    print_r( $aul1 );
    print_r( $aul2 );
```

Comment: Susan, you can use an XPath selector with this approach too. CSS selectors (such as `ul.outside.content`) are not possible unless you use another library.